# text region indent in emacs

Tags: emacs

I'm trying to make it

```
    It was the best of times ,
it was the worst of times,
it was the age of wisdom,
it was the age of foolishness.
```

like this

```
    It was the best of times ,
    it was the worst of times,
    it was the age of wisdom,
    it was the age of foolishness.
```

Sorry guys I'm a newbie...In the books it tells me using "ESC C-\" after setting region marks.
I tried but when I type Alt C the highlighted region disappear.

So can any guys help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a text-mode buffer if you mark the text in your first example and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> you will get the text in your second example.  This key combination runs the command `indent-region`.

I think you're tripping up on the syntax in the docs.  `C-x` means <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>.

Comment: sorry not C-M-\,this makes the indent of the first line disappear.

Comment: I wanna add indent for all the four lines.

Comment: Thanks very much.Now I found the reason.I included the first line in the region...Well,this make me feel a little bit shameful.

Comment: FWIW the same thing happened to me when I was in a mode other than text-mode.  Indentation is determined by the mode so in some cases removing the indent from the first line is what would be expected.